# How copy a file when emulate command is provided on IONIC 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an IONIC 2 application, and recently I added aws-sdk reference, like this:

```
npm install aws-sdk --save
```

My problem is when I run the command to emulate the application, the application show me an empty interface. And when I see the console, it tells me that region_config.json file is not found.

I think that to resolve this problem, I need to copy this file every time that I run the command to emulate the application. Also, I think that the solution is add a new script parameter in package.json file.

My problem is that I don't know what script add (I am in a Windows 10 Machine). For now, I'm trying with this:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "typings": "typings",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --copy .\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\lib\\region_config.json"
  },
```

And call like this

```
ionic emulate android
```

This is the console log

```
E:\GH\hunters.social\src\01 - clients\mobile>ionic emulate android

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build E:\GH\hunters.social\src\01 - clients\mobile
> ionic-app-scripts build

[13:58:07]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45
[13:58:07]  build prod started ...
[13:58:07]  clean started ...
[13:58:07]  clean finished in 7 ms
[13:58:07]  copy started ...
[13:58:07]  ngc started ...
[13:58:07]  copy finished in 208 ms
[13:58:49]  ngc finished in 42.23 s
[13:58:49]  webpack started ...
[13:59:04]  webpack finished in 15.29 s
[13:59:04]  uglifyjs started ...
[13:59:04]  sass started ...
[13:59:06]  sass finished in 1.53 s
[13:59:06]  cleancss started ...
[13:59:08]  cleancss finished in 1.91 s
[13:59:23]  uglifyjs finished in 18.75 s
[13:59:23]  build prod finished in 76.29 s
[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/tags/select-tags.ts, line: 20
            Unused method: 'ionViewWillEnter'

      L20:    private ionViewWillEnter() {
      L21:      this.dataset = this.eventTagsService.getEventTypes().map(x => { return { name: x.name, id: x.id, isSelected: false }});

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 6
            Unused import: 'GetDetailEventsResponse'

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 6
       L5:  import { CommonException, SessionExpiredException } from 'hunter-news-exceptions';
[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 8        L6:
import { DotDto, GetDetailEventsRequest, [13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 10 G
e[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 15
t[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 15 D
etailEventsRe[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/providers/event-service.ts, line: 395 s
ponse, GetResumeEventsRequest, GetResumeEventsRes
       L7:  import { LatLongEngine } from 'hunter-news-engines';

            Unused import: 'GetResumeEventsResponse'

       L5:  import { CommonException, SessionExpiredException } from 'hunter-news-exceptions';
       L6:  ilEventsRequest, GetDetailEventsResponse, GetResumeEventsRequest, GetResumeEventsResponse, EventInfoHeaderDt
       L7:  import { LatLongEngine } from 'hunter-news-engines';

            Unused import: 'Observable'

       L7:  import { LatLongEngine } from 'hunter-news-engines';
       L8:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
       L9:  import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

            Unused import: 'ResumeEventModel'

       L9:  import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
      L10:  import { DetailEventModel, ResumeEventModel } from '../custom/interfaces';
      L11:  import { EventIndex } from '../custom/events-index';

            Unused import: 'Facebook'

      L14:  import { LoginService } from './login-service';
      L15:  import { Facebook, NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
      L16:  declare var apigClientFactory: any;

            Unused import: 'NativeStorage'

      L14:  import { LoginService } from './login-service';
      L15:  import { Facebook, NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
      L16:  declare var apigClientFactory: any;

            Unused variable: 'wasAdded'

     L394:  let wasFound = false;
     L395:  let wasAdded = false;

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/camera/camera.ts, line: 21
            Unused method: 'ionViewWillEnter'

      L21:    private ionViewWillEnter() {
      L22:      this.takePhoto();

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/event/event.ts, line: 2
            Unused import: 'NavParams'

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/event/event.ts, line: 3        L1:
import { Component, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
       L2:  [13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/event/event.ts, line: 4
import { NavController, AlertController, Platform, [13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/event/event.ts, line: 7 N
a[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/event/event.ts, line: 108
vParams, LoadingController, ModalController, Events } f
       L3:  import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

            Unused import: 'Geolocation'

       L2:  import { NavController, AlertController, Platform, NavParams, LoadingController, ModalController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  import { Geoloc[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/event/event.ts, line: 114
ation } from 'ionic-native';
       L4:  import { DotDto } from 'hunter-news-interfaces';

            Unused import: 'DotDto'

       L3:  import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
       L4:  import { DotDto } from 'hunter-news-interfaces';
       L5:  import { EventService, EventCreating } from '../../providers/event-service';

            Unused import: 'MapPage'

       L6:  import { LoginService } from '../../providers/login-service';
       L7:  import { MapPage } from '../map/map';
       L8:  import { Logger } from '../../custom/logger';

            Unused method: 'ionViewWillEnter'

     L108:  private ionViewWillEnter() {
     L109:    this.events.subscribe(EventIndex.onTagsModalClose, this.onTagsModalClose.bind(this));

            Unused method: 'ionViewWillLeave'

     L114:    private ionViewWillLeave() {
     L115:      this._marker.remove();

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/map/map.ts, line: 7
            Unused import: 'Observable'

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/map/map.ts, line: 40        L6:
import { EventPage } from '../event/event';
[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/map/map.ts, line: 52
       L7:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
       L8:  import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

            Unused method: 'ionViewDidEnter'

      L39:  /** Evento gatillado cuando se activa la vista */
      L40:  private ionViewDidEnter() {
      L41:    try {

            Unused method: 'ionViewDidLeave'

      L51:  /** Destruye la página */
      L52:  private ionViewDidLeave() {
      L53:    try {

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 2
            Unused import: 'NavParams'

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 3
       L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
       L2:  import { NavController, AlertController, Platform, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  import { Facebook, NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';

            Unused import: 'NativeStorage'

       L2:  import { NavController, AlertController, Platform, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  import { Facebook, NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
       L4:  import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

[13:59:28]  tslint: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/src/app/app.component.ts, line: 3
            Unused import: 'NativeStorage'

       L2:  import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
       L4:  import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\vvene\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.


:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileLint

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:bundleDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary

UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library

UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2340Library

UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42411Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4141Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase980Library
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement980Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation980Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps980Library
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks980Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugNdk
UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders

UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders

UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE

:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
 UP-TO-DATE

:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE

:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:validateSigningDebug

:packageDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:cdvBuildDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.459 secs

Built the following apk(s):
        E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\vvene\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Skipping build...


Built the following apk(s):
        E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Using apk: E:/GH/hunters.social/src/01 - clients/mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Package name: social.hunters.news

INSTALL SUCCESS


LAUNCH SUCCESS



E:\GH\hunters.social\src\01 - clients\mobile>
```

But it does not work. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: can you post console logs you see?

Comment: I recently put the console log.